# Active vs passive voice

Tags: passive-voice, active-voice

I am always in confuse with news heading and paragraph content.
Here in this image the heading sentence seems in active voice and in paragraph it is in passive voice, the result is like the actor has been changed.[image]
Could you explain?

Comment: Headlines have their own conventions. There's no reason why the headline (or any other sort of heading text) should be in the same voice as the paragraphs that follow. Having said that, I'd have said that *that* headline is in the passive voice - it's essentially the same as the first sentence under the picture.

Comment: The word _were_ has been left out of the headline for brevity.

Comment: The paper uses passive in headline and article to avoid overstating the point of *who* killed the Maoists. It looks like the security forces did, but the paper remains neutral on that point, as there could be other explanations.